# cv2 imwrite and german letters ("ä, ü, ö")

Tags: python, encoding, opencv, save-image

I wrote a script to manipulate some pictures with `cv2` in python.
Now I need to save these files, but some of the filenames contain german letters  `("ä, ü, ö")`.
Unfortunately it seems the `cv2`function `imwrite()` can't handle this and writes the filenames as **BÃ¶gen** instead of **Bögen**.
I tried to convert the `pathname` to `UTF-8` and other encodings via

```
path.encode("utf-8")
```

but this just leads to a

```
"TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation"
```

Has anyone any experience with problems like that?

Comment: Please give all information and code required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, OpenCV `imwrite` method only supports ASCII characters.

To display UTF-8 characters, we need to use PIL Library.

See the example below, implementing a new function `print_utf8` is a simple solution for this task:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def print_utf8(image, text, color):  
    fontName = 'FreeSerif.ttf'
    font = ImageFont.truetype(fontName, 18)  
    img_pil = Image.fromarray(image)  
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)  
    draw.text((0, image.shape[0] - 30), text, font=font,
           fill=(color[0], color[1], color[2], 0)) 
    image = np.array(img_pil) 
    return image

img = cv2.imread("myImage.png")

color = (255, 0, 0) #red text
img_with_text = print_utf8(img, "ä, ü, ö",color)
cv2.imshow('IMAGE', img_with_text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Converting to a PIL-image and then using the ".save()"-Method solved my Problem!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: And for anyone using the same method to solve a problem like this, remember:  
cv2 uses BGR for encoding color, while PIL uses RGB. To solve this use: `cv2_im = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_pil = Image.fromarray(cv2_im)
    img_pil.save(spath)`